# std::sort in a template function

Tags: c++, templates

This is the part of my code that doesn't work:

```
template<typename T>
list<T> f(list<list<T> >& lst,
          void (*op)(list<T>&, list<T>&))
{
    list<list<T> >::iterator itr = lst.begin();

    int count = 0;
    for_each(lst.begin(), lst.end(),
             [&count](list<T> l){ count += l.size(); });

    list<T> res(count);
    res.insert(res.end(), itr->begin(), itr->end());

    sort(res.begin(), res.end());

    return res;
}
```

VS2012 compiler says error C2784:

```
error C2784: ''unknown-type' std::operator -(std::move_iterator<_RanIt> &,const 
std::move_iterator<_RanIt2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 
'std::move_iterator<_RanIt> &' from 'std::_List_iterator<_Mylist>'
```

I tried calling

```
sort<T>(res.begin(), res.end());
```

but got the message:

```
cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::_List_iterator<_Mylist>' to 'int'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I cannot tell you why those particular error messages, what I can tell you is that `std::sort` requires random access iterators, and `std::list<>::iterator` are not such.

You can use `std::list<>::sort()`

---

Actually the first error message is not that hard to understand. The implementation has attempted to substract two list iterators, and there is no operator to do that. ADL brought the `std` namespace into the search and the compiler found the overload of `operator-` to substract two `std::move_iterator<>` (of random iterators), but the template type `_RanIt` is in a non-deducible context and that failed. Just focus on the core issue: the compiler could not find a valid `operator-`

The second error message is related to the fact that you provided the wrong template argument. The type argument to the `std::sort` template is the iterator type, and the signature is:

```
template <typename Iterator>
std::sort(Iterator begin, Iterator end);
```

When you provided `T` (which seems to be `int` in this case) the compiler generated the specialization:

```
template <>
std::sort(int begin, int end)
```

But in your call you are trying to pass `std::list<int>::iterator` as argument, and the compiler cannot convert from that into `int`.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) on a `std::list` because a `list` is not random-access (more specifically, its iterators are not [`RandomAccessIterators`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator)).

If you want to sort a `list`, use its member function [`std::list<T>::sort()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/sort) instead:

```
list<T> res(count);
res.insert(res.end(), itr->begin(), itr->end());
res.sort();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Guess C++ is a language that requires some reading before starting to code templates :P .